# Connect to SQL Server CE in stimulsoft

Tags: sql-server-ce, stimulsoft

I want Stimulsoft software wizard to connect to SQL Server CE

How can the stimulsoft software to connect to a SQL Server CE database ?

Answer (score 0):

You could download the SQL Server CE adapter from Stimulsoft site and compile it with assemblies that you use. You will find instruction in the archive.